# Select from DataTable most recent result for each item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable

I have a datatable containing thousands of rows. in the table there is a serial number column and a test number column. If a serial is tested more than one the test number increments. I need to be able to select the most recent test for each serial from my datatable and insert it into another datatable. Currently I am using this:

```
    DataTable newdata = data.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<Int16>("Test") == 
                data.AsEnumerable().Where(y => y.Field<string>("Serial") == 
                    x.Field<string>("SerialNumber")).Select(y => 
                        y.Field<Int16>("Test")).Max()).Select(x => x).CopyToDataTable();
```

This does do the job however as it is quite clear it is incredibly inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to select the top row of data for each serial number?

Thank you

**Solution**

So following on from Cam Bruce's answer I implemented the following code with a Dictionary rather than with a join:

```
    //Get all of the serial numbers and there max test numbers
    Dictionary<string, Int16> dict = data.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("SerialNumber")).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Max(y => y.Field<Int16>("Test")));

    //Create a datatable with only the max rows
    DataTable newdata = data.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<Int16>("Test") == 
                dict[x.Field<string>("SerialNumber")]).Select(x => x).CopyToDataTable();

    //Clear the dictionary
    dict.Clear();
```

Comment: Can you write SQL to perform this logic? It would be *much* more efficient then scanning the entire `DataTable`

Comment: Getting the value from `sql` and displaying in `datatable` is the efficient way

Comment: Unfortunately the nature of the software dictates that I cannot efficiently query the SQL database.

Comment: Not the nature of the software sorry - the nature of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you each serial number, and the `Max` test. You can then join that result set back to the `DataTable` to get all the max rows.

```
var maxTest= data.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(g=> g.Field<string>("SerialNumber"))
                  .Select(d=> new
                  {
                     SerialNumber = g.Key
                     Test = g.Max(g.Field<Int16>("Field"))
                  };

var maxRows = from d in data.AsEnumerable()
              join m in maxTest
              on new { S = d.Field<string>("SerialNumber"), T = d.Field<Int16>("Test") } 
              equals new { S = m.SerialNumber, T = m.Test }
              select d;
```

Comment: Ohh, that's sweet. I didn't think to break it out into two sections with a join. I'll put it in and see how it runs! Cheers

Comment: I have amended the original question so show the final solution, based on the idea of your answer just slightly different.